# Not understanding code used in TensorFlow MNIST guide

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist, softmax

I'm reading through the [MNIST TensorFlow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners), and trying to get a good understanding of what's going on.

The first set of steps, with added comments, looks like this:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

# Download the data set.
# Comprises thousands of images, each with a label.
# Our images are 28x28, so we have 784 pixels in total.
# one_hot means our labels are treated as a vector with a
# length of 10. e.g. for the number 4, it'd be
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

# x isn't a specific value. It's a placeholder, a value that
# we'll input when we ask TensorFlow to run a computation.
# We want to input any number of MNIST images, each flattened
# into a 784-dimensional vector (e.g. an array made up of a
# double for each pixel, representing pixel brightness).
# Takes the form of [Image, Pixel].
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

# Variables are modifiable tensors, which live in TensorFlow's
# graph of interacting operations. It can be used and modified
# by the computation. Model parameters are usually set as Variables.

# Weights
# Takes the form of [Pixel, Digit]
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))

# Biases
# Takes the form of [Digit]
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

So now I'm trying to breakdown this last line to figure out what's going on.

They provide this diagram:

[image]

Ignoring the `softmax` step, and ignoring the adding of biases, so just looking at that top line:

`(W1,1 * x1) + (W1,2 * x2) + (W1,3 * x3)`.

Since x is now 1-dimensional, I'll assume it's specific to a particular image, and so the x value is each pixel within that image. We thus have:

`(Weight of 1st pixel for 1st digit * value of 1st pixel) + (Weight of 1st pixel for 2nd digit * value of 2nd pixel) + (Weight of 1st pixel for 3rd digit * value of 3rd pixel)`

This doesn't seem right. The weight tensor's first dimension representing pixels, where the `x` tensor's second dimension represents pixels, means we're multiplying the values of different pixels... this doesn't make any sense to me.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model is *very simple* and probably isn't worth of in-depth discussion, but your conclusion isn't correct. Pixel values are never multiplied. This is a linear model:

```
tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```

... which naively assumes an image is a bunch of independent pixels. Each pixel gets multiplied by different weights corresponding to 10 classes. In other words, this linear layer assigns a weight to each `(pixel, class)` pair. This directly corresponds to its shape: `[784, 10]` (I'm ignoring the bias term for simplicity).

As a result of this multiplication, a final 10-length vector contains the scores for each class. Each score takes into account each pixel, more precisely it's a *weighted sum* of all pixel values. The score then goes to the loss function to compare the output with the ground truth, so that in the next iteration we could tweak those weights in the right direction.

Though it's very simple, it is still a reasonable approach.